# Javascript — How to assign multiple elements to an object?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object, react-native

I am trying to assign multiple elements to an object without success. The data is being overridden rather than added. I am new to this, therefore I am unsure if `Object.assing()` is the right option. How can I add multiple sets of data to an object?

**Pseudo-code**

- Select the start date
- Add to object
- Select end date
- Add to object
- Get dates in between and add to object

**Code**

```
_selectDate = obj => {
    let selection = {}
    const { startDate, endDate } = this.state

    if (!startDate) {
        Object.assign(selection, {
            [obj.dateString]: { startingDay: true, color: 'black', textColor: 'white' },
        })
    } else {
        Object.assign(selection, {
            [obj.dateString]: { endingDay: true, color: 'black', textColor: 'white' },
        })
    }

    this.setState({
        startDate: !startDate,
        test: selection,
    })
}
```

**Outcome desired**

```
{
    '2018-08-20': { startingDay: true, color: 'black', textColor: 'white' },
    '2018-08-21': { selected: true, color: 'black', textColor: 'white' },
    '2018-08-22': { selected: true, color: 'black', textColor: 'white' },
    '2018-08-04': { endingDay: true, color: 'black', textColor: 'white' },
}
```

Comment: Can you please post what is the input for the desired outcome?

Comment: DRY. And is endingDate before startingDay?

Comment: Sorry @DSCH but what do you mean by input? The data comes from a click in a calendar (react-native-calendars). Based on the click, I am structuring the data in the way required by the module `[obj.dateString]: { startingDay: true, color: 'black', textColor: 'white' }`. That gets passed to the calendar and the day gets highlighted.  Unfortunately everytime I click, the data gets overwritten instead added. @mplungjan No, startingDay should be the first, followed by endingDay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you create new object on each call:

```
let selection = {}
```

That is why you cannot 'accumulate' this data.

For fix this you should get it from your state, like this:

```
let selection = this.state.test
```

And then (in if statement) make assignment:

```
selection = {
   ...selection,
   [obj.dateString]: { 
      endingDay: true, 
      color: 'black', 
      textColor: 'white' 
   },
}
```

Comment: Let me try this. Brb.

Comment: it works. It fixes the issue. Now I need to make it DRY and figure it out a way to get the in-between dates. One last thing, why the `...selection`? What does it do? Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: `...selection` gets all existed fields of `selection`. And then we construct a new object adding to existed fields new one.